# javascript - Need to pull data out of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

Hi I have a datatables based table that holds data. I need to be able to get the values out of the following string that I have been able to do so far.

```
<input name="jobNo" value="job_no_123" />job_no_123
```

I need to be able to get the name and the value and store into separate variables that I then pass off to do something else.

However I do also have another 4 fields on the page that I need to capture too:

```
<input name="item_1" value="data1" />data1
<input name="item_2" value="data2" />data2
<input name="item_3" value="data3" />data3
<input name="item_4" value="data4" />data4
```

And of top of this, this would only be the data from one row, and I need to do this for multiple rows too. But I need to start somewhere.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are your needs but here is a code that should help

```
$('input').each(function(i, val){
    $(this).attr('name'); // will get the attribute name
    $(this).attr('value'); // will get the attribute value
    $(this).attr('text');  // will get the text inside the input
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex can find the values from your code. However, it assumes that the input is strictly in that format, with no variations in even whitespace.

```
<input name="(.*)" value="(.*)" />
```

The values will be in captured groups 1 and 2.

Note: I am aware that regex should not be used to parse HTML, but if the input is strict enough, it works.

Comment: Why? Why would you ever want to do that when you have jQuery available?

Comment: The question mentioned the input "in a string", not in the DOM. (Though the string may very well have been obtained from the DOM.)

Comment: You can change that string to DOM easily. RegEx can get the job done though.